# Averaging numpy array over for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating a numpy array each iteration of a for loop. How do I average that?

For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    array_that_I_calculate = some_calculation(x,y,z)
```

Comment: whats the shape of the array, can you give some samples?

Comment: Each `array_that_I_calculate` is 2000 x 1

Comment: and whats your expected outputs shape?

Comment: An average of each element that is also 2000 x 1

Comment: ohk, just append them to a list and then use `np.average` over `axis 0 `of that list of arrays. details in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

1. Append the `array_that_I_calculate` at each iteration into a `list_of_arrays`
2. After the loop ends, take `np.average()` of `list_of_arrays` over `axis=0`

```py
import numpy as np


##### IGNORE #####
#dummy function that returns (2000,1) array

def some_calculation(x=None,y=None,z=None)
    return np.random.random((2000,1))


##### SOLUTION #####

list_of_arrays = []                                  #<-----

for i in range(5):
    array_that_I_calculate = some_calculation(x,y,z)
    list_of_arrays.append(array_that_I_calculate)    #<-----
    
averaged_array = np.average(list_of_arrays, axis=0)  #<-----
print(averaged_array.shape)
```

```
(2000,1)
```

Comment: do let me know if that solved your question. feel free to mark the answer if it did. thanks!